# Can I use CSS to replace a large icon with smaller icon?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that changes shopping cart icons when you scroll. In its original state, a very large icon is displayed. Upon scroll, a smaller, more desirable icon is displayed. I am wanting to replace the larger icon with the smaller icon at all times but I am having trouble targeting the larger icon in the code. How can I replace the larger icon at all times? My site is https://pennwoods.com.

I have opened the dev tools in Chrome and targeted each div. When I make a change that affects the larger icon, it seems to have the same effect on the smaller one. I am a CSS rookie.

```
element.style {
    /* display: none; */
}
.top-form.top-form-minicart {
    padding: 12px 10px 1px 1px;
}
.top-form.top-form-minicart {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 26px 24px 18px;
    background: #617348;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
}
.top-form {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
*, html {
    outline: 0!important;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


div {
    display: block;
}
```

I am expecting the smaller icon to show at all times in place of the large icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.top-form.top-form-minicart {
   padding: 6px 5px 1px 1px;
}
.top-form.top-form-minicart {
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 13px 12px 9px;
   background: #617348;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
   -o-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
   -ms-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
   border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
}
```

Please change the padding. I have reduced it by half.

Answer (score 2):

Change `font-size` in `before` to resize(`16px` to match the other icons) your icon.

And also you need to change `padding: 40px 10px 0px;`

Nice catch by Madhu Jayarama.

[image]

```css
.top-form.top-form-minicart .top-minicart-icon:before {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.top-form.top-form-minicart .top-minicart-icon .minicart-number {
  right: 0px;
}

.top-form.top-form-minicart {
  padding: 40px 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That changes the size of the icon but the alignment is off. I want it to be inline with the rest of the navigation bar. Ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking into. Did you custom-style the cart and number?

Comment: No...it came with the theme. It is default or at least not handled in the customizer.

Comment: Thanks you guys. Life savers!